# Difference in usage between 'If I were you, I would X' and 'If I were you, I would have Xed'

Tags: word-usage, conditionals, irrealis-were

"If I were you, I would look for another job" and "if I were you, I would have looked for another job" 
what is the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: @john Lawler what do you think?

Comment: From the way you phrased your question, I find it strange that you shouldn't know the difference.

Comment: My mother tongue is not English its Marathi. Thats why I have problem in this. And I am confused in this part of usage only @centaurus

Comment: The first is correct, the second is incorrect.There are several possibilities, e.g.
1) Had I been you, I would have looked for another job

2) If I'd have been you, I'd have looked for another job

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Says who? Please produce evidence that the second sentence is not grammatical.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

The first statement,

> If I were you, I would look for another job.

suggests that the advised action is something that the person to whom the sentence is addressed can perform to beneficial effect right now.

The second statement,

> If I were you, I would have looked for another job.

implies that the action would have been appropriate in the past, but that there is no guarantee that doing it now is potentially beneficial or even possible.

Comment: +1 Or simply put, *I would do it **now*** or *I would have done it **back then***

Answer (score 0):

> If I were you, I would look for another job

The speaker is suggesting that looking for a different job is something they would do **today** in that person's position. We do not know if the person being spoken to is currently working, or has recently found a new job. It's most likely the former; perhaps the person is unhappy at work; their salary is too low; or there are rumours of downsizing (often called in BrEng *redundancies*) etc. **But nothing excludes the possibility that this person is out of work, and is currently seeking employment.**

> If I were you, I would have looked for another job

“I” am speaking in the present, but like the previous statement, my being “you” is only  hypothetical. The person being spoken to ***might* be currently employed**, perhaps they accepted a job position half-heartedly, we don't have enough information to know for certain. However, I'm suggesting that if I had been in his situation, I would have looked elsewhere for employment.  This type of construction is often labelled *[mixed conditionals](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/mixedconditional.html)*

Example:

> *If I were rich, I would have bought that Ferrari we saw yesterday*
>   <sub>But I am not currently rich and that is why I didn't buy the Ferrari yesterday</sub>